# Is a crime committed by using a made bed in an unused bedroom?

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales, trespass, criminal-damage

Bob once noticed that a particular door’s remote entry system was misconfigured (thus not properly locking the door upon it being closed) at an inpatient facility and that upon entering, there is a guest bedroom apparently used for patients’ visitors who find themselves needing accommodations overnight where the door is also unlocked.

One day he needs a place to crash and all the trains are finished for the night so he decides to let himself into this guest bedroom as it is already 2:00am and nobody apparently needed it for that night and the bed linens are already made etc.

Perhaps he has brought a date there and they have sex in the bed. (Would this make any difference if he did?)

Have any crimes been committed by Bob, and/or his date, and if so, what?

The main candidates (non-exhaustive) seem to me to be aggravated trespass, in case someone comes along and legitimately needs the room but cannot use it, though possibly not applicable otherwise, and criminal damage although I’m not sure if it would be barred by de minimis thresholds. I’m not confident of the applicability of either of these suggestions, nor of the right parameters of their respective caveats.

Comment: Have a butchers at this https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2008/4/part/8/crossheading/nuisance-or-disturbance-on-hospital-premises?view=plain

Answer (score 1):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

Trespass, theft of services, criminal damaging, burglary/breaking and entering.

Comment: I’ve never heard of criminal damage be used as a compound verb or indeed otherwise than as effectively a noun phrase for the name of a crime. I’ve never heard it be given tenses.

Comment: No breaking in England though if you entered peacefully. And trespass isn’ta crime. If it was a bed and breakfast with rooms on offer for payment and I could see theft of services but otherwise doesn’t seem tenable.

Comment: Burglary would require keeping something from the facility as a souvenir.

Comment: Criminal damage is the only thing out of there that I can sort of see sticking but it seems like it would also be subject to a de minimis threshold.

Comment: Sounds like you already know the answer to your question.

Comment: not very well, I think it just sounds like you possibly don’t. I remain unsure of possibilities of aggravated trespass and of criminal damage. And also not sure if there are other possibilities I’m not thinking of.